# How to programmatically add a folder to Favorites in Windows File Explorer

Tags: windows

I am aware of the solutions answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4271759/how-do-i-programmatically-add-a-folder-to-the-users-favorites-in-windows-explo). Basically the idea is to create a link to folder in the `%USERPROFILE%\Favoriates` folder.

However it doesn't work for me. I'm using Windows8 (don't know if that matters). In my `%USERPROFILE%\Favoriates`, it contains favoriate items for IE, not the file explorer.

I tried to locate this settings in registry and file system by creating a folder with very unique name and adding it to file explorer favoriates. Then search for the name in registry and file system. Didn't yield anything.

Comment: The Favorites list is intended to be under user control. Applications should not be inserting them into the user's Favorites. This leads to unhappy users.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you want %UserProfile%\Links.

[image: Pinned favorites]

Answer (score 4):

Programmatically, you want to retrieve the location using [SHGetKnownFolderPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762188%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) with [KNOWNFOLDERID_Links](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762584%28v=VS.85%29.aspx), instead of hard-coding any location, and then use `IShellLink` to create the shortcut file in that location.

Here is a C# example for the first part:

```cs
[DllImport("shell32.dll")]
static extern int SHGetKnownFolderPath(
                      [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStruct)] Guid knownFolderId, 
                      uint flags,
                      IntPtr userToken,
                      [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] out string knownFolderPath);

// this corresponds to the KNOWNFOLDERID_Links constant:
public static readonly Guid Links = new Guid("bfb9d5e0-c6a9-404c-b2b2-ae6db6af4968");

public static string GetKnownFolderPath(Guid knownFolderId)
{
    string path;
    int result = SHGetKnownFolderPath(knownFolderId, 0, IntPtr.Zero, out path);
    // … (error handling; check result for E_FAIL, E_INVALIDARG, or S_OK)
    return path;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ah, looks like for Windows 8 this location has changed to `%USERPROFILE%\Links`, rather than `%USERPROFILE%\Favoriates`.

So to answer my question. To programmically add a folder to the Favoriates in Windows 8 file explorer, you need to make a link to that folder in the `%USERPROFILE%\Links` folder:

```
mklink /D %USERPROFILE%\Links\<Link_Name> <Tartget_Folder_Path>
```

Comment: Don't hard code paths.  Use the API (e.g., SHGetKnownFolderPath) to get the correct path.

Answer (score 0):

The Explorer Favorites are stored here `%USERPROFILE%\Links`.

Answer (score 0):

```
Function AddAFolderShortCut($fileName, $targetPath)
{
    Write-Host "Creating Shortcut $fileName points to $targetPath"
    $WshShell = New-Object -comObject WScript.Shell
    $Shortcut = $WshShell.CreateShortcut("$env:USERPROFILE\Links\$fileName.lnk")
    $Shortcut.TargetPath = $targetPath
    $Shortcut.Save()
}

AddAFolderShortCut "FolderName" "C:\folderpath"
```