# How do I get the name of each item in windows 10 'quick access' items list and put it on a list?

Tags: c#, windows, list

In Windows 10 or possibly lesser windows versions, there is a 'quick access' icon that shows up when you have documents folder open on the left side. I just want to get the names of each item in that 'quick access' list and put it .ToList();, how do I do this?
PS, I'm not trying to add a folder to quick access like the other answered questions in these links:
[Is it possible programmatically add folders to the Windows 10 Quick Access panel in the explorer window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30051634/is-it-possible-programmatically-add-folders-to-the-windows-10-quick-access-panel)

[How to programmatically add a folder to Favorites in Windows File Explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16656342/how-to-programmatically-add-a-folder-to-favorites-in-windows-file-explorer/16656433#16656433)

I'm trying to get the names of each item on that panel, not add folders to it.

[image: windows quick access]

Comment: Please read [ask] and try searching before asking a question, and include that research in your question. There's no API for what you want, see duplicate.

Comment: well, nvm I read the post and yea it answers this question

Comment: Whether you want to add, delete, edit or list items does not matter, the principle remains the same: there's no API, because then every other application would add itself to it. You can probably list it by iterating the relevant registry keys.

Answer (score 3):

Here is some code that dumps it to the console:

```
// get this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/shell-application
dynamic shell = Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetTypeFromProgID("Shell.Application"));

// this is Quick Access folder id
var CLSID_HomeFolder = new Guid("679f85cb-0220-4080-b29b-5540cc05aab6");
var quickAccess = shell.Namespace("shell:::" + CLSID_HomeFolder.ToString("B"));
foreach (var item in quickAccess.Items())
{
    var grouping = (int)item.ExtendedProperty("System.Home.Grouping");
    switch (grouping)
    {
        case 1:
            Console.WriteLine("Frequent: " + item.Name + " path: " + item.Path);
            break;

        case 2:
            Console.WriteLine("Recent: " + item.Name + " path: " + item.Path);
            break;

        default:
            Console.WriteLine("Unspecified: " + item.Name + " path: " + item.Path);
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you explain why the extendedproperty is 'System.Home.Grouping'? Cause i'm not able to get any information about this property or 'System.Home' class.

Comment: @Hellagur - indeed, this property is not officially documented by Microsoft

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Cause i found the file group differs between win10 and win11. In win10 it's 2 while in win11 it's 3, which really made me confused.