# How do I get a list of Windows Explorer Favorites shortcuts (*.lnk)?

Tags: c#, winforms, list, shortcut, favorites

I'm building a custom open file dialog and want to display the same list of favorites that appears in the left pane of a Windows Explorer dialog. How do I get a list of Windows Explorer Favorites shortcuts (*.lnk)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Windows Explorer `Favorites` shortcuts are are stored in {SystemDrive}:\users{AccountName}\links. So, something like this will do it in C#

```
string pathToLinks = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("USERPROFILE") + "\\Links";
string[] fileEntries = Directory.GetFiles(pathToLinks, "*.lnk);
```

Comment: Use `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Favorites)` instead of `Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("USERPROFILE") + "\\Links"` due to the fact that the user could have modified his favorites location

Comment: `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Favorites)` returns the location of Internet Explorer browser Favorites (not the list of favorites that appears in the left pane of a Windows Explorer dialog). I'm not sure if the location of Windows Explorer Favorites (`%USERPROFILE%\Links`) can be changed

Comment: wouldn't you do Directory.GetFiles(pathToLinks, "*.lnk); to filter instead of filtering in the loop?

Comment: @NovaSysEng [You can change the location](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1IL16fMMr11NpaOjygbQQJgalCtm0X9sw) but there is a (quite complicated) solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27987197/6730162

Comment: @TobiasBrohl Thanks - I'll take a look and I'll design my application to let the user browse to the location of their choice (with "USERPROFILE") + "\\Links" being the default if it exists) and set it as a default for my app