# Create shortcut in Favorites with filepath C#

Tags: c#, special-folders

I have the following code below. I can't seem to get it to work for adding a folder to favorites. If I change it to specialfolders.desktop, it creates a shortcut on the desktop.

```
private void buttonAddFav_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string userName = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;
        string targetPath = listFolderResults.SelectedItem.ToString();
        var wsh = new IWshShell_Class();
        IWshRuntimeLibrary.IWshShortcut shortcut = wsh.CreateShortcut(
            Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Favorites) + "\\shorcut2.lnk") as IWshRuntimeLibrary.IWshShortcut;
        shortcut.TargetPath = targetPath;
        shortcut.Save();
    }
```

[image]

Comment: what do you mean by 'favorites', can you upload a screen capture?

Comment: the favorites section in windows explorer. I just added an image

Comment: which OS are you testing on?

Comment: I'm using Windows 7

Comment: can you have a try following this [social msdn](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/4d65a7e5-1c02-4c18-bbc0-8d49340ca5f7/how-can-i-add-folders-to-favorites-in-window-explrer-programmatically-c?forum=csharpgeneral)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I programmatically add a folder to the user's Favorites (in Windows Explorer)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4271759/how-do-i-programmatically-add-a-folder-to-the-users-favorites-in-windows-explo)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Environment.SpecialFolder.Favorites` represents the folder that contains your **Internet Explorer favorites**, which are located in the `%USERPROFILE%\Favorites` folder.

There is no `Environment.SpecialFolder` value that represents your **Windows Explorer favorites**, which are located in the `%USERPROFILE%\Links` folder.

To retrieve the path to the `Links` folder, you will have to query the Shell directly for the `FOLDERID_Links` path using either:

1. PInvoke to call [`SHKnownFolderPath()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762188.aspx).
2. COM interop to call [`IKnownFolderManager.GetFolder()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761738.aspx) and then [`IKnownFolder.GetPath()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761762.aspx).

Comment: I am still pretty new to C#. Could you write out the example for how to go about this for me? Thank you!

Comment: @SeanDon Check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4271759/how-do-i-programmatically-add-a-folder-to-the-users-favorites-in-windows-explo

Answer (score 1):

The below code ended up working for me. The answers below were helpful in figuring out I need to build around the %userprofile%\links, but %userprofile% gave me errors when saving. When I used the method below, it worked.

```
string userName = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;
        string targetPath = listFolderResults.SelectedItem.ToString();
        string shortcutPath = string.Format(@"C:\Users\{0}\Links",Environment.UserName);
        MessageBox.Show(shortcutPath);

        var wsh = new IWshShell_Class();
        IWshRuntimeLibrary.IWshShortcut shortcut = wsh.CreateShortcut(
            shortcutPath + string.Format(@"\{0}.lnk",textFavName.Text)) as IWshRuntimeLibrary.IWshShortcut;
        shortcut.TargetPath = targetPath;
        shortcut.Save();
```

Comment: This code is not safe since you made assumption that the location of the Links folder is located in C:\Users\<user name>. But this special folder location can be changed. Right click the Links folder in Windows Explorer then click the Location tab and enter the physical folder location for Links special folder. So your code will fail if the user has moved his Links folder to somewhere else, eg. a folder in different partition.

Comment: Great hint! We may use Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile) + @"\Links", instead of static string. Thanks.